Show tag score in flair instead of badge count
Currently when you answer a question your flair shows up with your total stack overflow score and badge count.

At a glance this gives superficial credibility to the answer because "this person has a lot of points and badges so they must know what they're talking about".
But in my opinion, it may be more useful to replace badge counts with relevant tag scores. For example just because I answer a lot of c++ and python questions doesn't mean you should trust my go answers.
As an example, if someone asks a question with python and numpy it would be useful to generate a badge like this (excuse my horrible UX mock)

Thoughts?

Do you envision this change only for answer signatures or also for the asker signatures?

Plus it'll look a little awkward when there are 5 tags and the user has scores in all 5..☺

Hasn't this been already proposed before? I vaguely recall a discussion about it somewhere. p.s. here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239149/add-score-for-each-question-tags-in-the-user-card-below-each-answer

Frankly though, isn't the only credibility required is "does the answer work" for the OP? The rep of the answerer is functionally irrelevant.

@Paulie_D I agree that the actual answer is the most important part. My idea was that if the flair was going to serve any (superficial) purpose, it might as well try to do a better job at it

Meh, those MSE answers aren't very convincing. Based on their answers, it doesn't make sense why we have rep and badges at all on the nameplate either.

One point that hasn't been mentioned is that tag score is probably more of an indication about how much someone enjoys answering that tag, not their expertise in it.

@tdy There is conversation about that too somewhere. Each answer should be judged based on its own merits, end of discussion. It doesn't matter if a user has 1M+ rep or 100+ of badges; their answers may be wrong, outdated, or in violation of network rules. So, answers on MSE argue against including a flair with scores altogether, and by inclusion, they argue against the tag score as well. Moreover, tag score can cause even stronger illusion that someone's answer is better than the others', compared to the effect of the current version of the flair. So, IMO, this feature should be declined.

And here I thought Office Space killed flair.

Clarification: is this only for flair on post, or also for sharable flair from Settings?
